# Implementation of std::vector class

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel, vectors

I decided to implement the `std::vector` class in C++, and was wondering if I had done everything correctly. When I mean 'correctly', I mean that the code is efficiently written and done properly. I have tested all the functions using various tests and they seem to output correct results.

I have not included every function in the `std` class: the main ones that I have not included are `assign`/`insert` and I have not implemented a `reverse_iterator`, although I have made my own `iterator` and `const_iterator` class.

```
# include <memory>
// I included the below two headers for my tests
# include <iostream>
# include <string>

namespace mynamespace
{
template <typename T, typename A>
class vector;

template<typename Vec_T>
class vector_const_iterator;

template<typename Vec_T>
class vector_iterator
    {
public:
    typedef vector_iterator<Vec_T> this_t;
    typedef typename Vec_T::value_type T;

    friend Vec_T;

    vector_iterator(T *ptr_, Vec_T const &cont)
        : container(cont),
        ptr(ptr_)
        {
        }

    vector_iterator(this_t const &rhs)
        : container(rhs.container),
        ptr(rhs.ptr)
        {
        }

    vector_iterator(vector_const_iterator<Vec_T> const &rhs)
        : container(rhs.container),
        ptr(rhs.ptr)
        {
        }

    ~vector_iterator()
        {
        }

    bool operator!=(this_t const &rhs) const
        {
        return (ptr != rhs.ptr);
        }

    bool operator!=(T *ptr_) const
        {
        return (ptr != ptr_);
        }

    bool operator==(this_t const &rhs) const
        {
        return (ptr == rhs.ptr);
        }

    bool operator==(T *ptr_) const
        {
        return (ptr == ptr_);
        }

    bool operator>(this_t const &rhs) const
        {
        return (ptr > rhs.ptr);
        }

    bool operator>(T *ptr_) const
        {
        return (ptr > ptr_);
        }

    bool operator>=(this_t const &rhs) const
        {
        return (ptr >= rhs.ptr);
        }

    bool operator>=(T *ptr_) const
        {
        return (ptr >= ptr_);
        }

    bool operator<(this_t const &rhs) const
        {
        return (ptr < rhs.ptr);
        }

    bool operator<(T *ptr_) const
        {
        return (ptr < ptr_);
        }

    bool operator<=(this_t const &rhs) const
        {
        return (ptr <= rhs.ptr);
        }

    bool operator<=(T *ptr_) const
        {
        return (ptr <= ptr_);
        }

    T &operator*()
        {
        if (is_valid_ptr())
            {
            return (*ptr);
            }
        throw std::exception("vector_iterator: pointer out of safe range when dereferencing (operator*)");
        }

    T *operator->()
        {
        if (is_valid_ptr())
            {
            return (ptr);
            }
        throw std::exception("vector_iterator: pointer out of safe range when dereferencing (operator->)");
        }

    this_t operator++(int)
        {
        this_t holder(*this);
        ++(*this);
        return (holder);
        }

    this_t &operator++()
        {
        ++ptr;
        return (*this);
        }

    this_t operator+=(unsigned offset)
        {
        ptr += offset;
        return (*this);
        }

    this_t &operator-=(unsigned offset)
        {
        ptr -= offset;
        return (*this);
        }

    T &operator[](unsigned offset) const
        {
        this_t holder(*this);
        holder.ptr += offset;
        if (holder.is_valid_ptr())
            {
            return (*(ptr + offset));
            }
        throw std::exception("vector_iterator: pointer out of safe range when dereferencing (operator[])");
        }

    this_t &operator=(this_t const &rhs)
        {
        ptr = rhs.ptr;
        return (*this);
        }

    this_t operator+(unsigned offset)
        {
        return (this_t(ptr + offset, container));
        }

    this_t operator-(unsigned offset)
        {
        return (this_t(ptr - offset, container));
        }

    unsigned operator-(this_t const &rhs)
        {
        return (ptr - rhs.ptr);
        }

    this_t operator--(int)
        {
        this_t holder(*this);
        --(*this);
        return (holder);
        }

    this_t &operator--()
        {
        --ptr;
        return (*this);
        }

    operator vector_const_iterator<Vec_T>()
        {
        return (vector_const_iterator<Vec_T>(ptr, container));
        }

private:
    Vec_T const &container;
    T *ptr;

    bool is_valid_ptr() const
        {
        return (ptr >= container.mem_start
            && ptr < container.seq_end);
        }

    bool is_valid_ptr2() const
        {
        return (ptr >= container.mem_start
            && ptr <= container.seq_end);
        }
    };

template<typename Vec_T>
class vector_const_iterator
    {
public:
    typedef vector_const_iterator<Vec_T> this_t;
    typedef typename Vec_T::value_type T;

    friend Vec_T;

    vector_const_iterator(T *ptr_, Vec_T const &cont)
        : container(cont),
        ptr(ptr_)
        {
        }

    vector_const_iterator(this_t const &rhs)
        : container(rhs.container),
        ptr(rhs.ptr)
        {
        }

    vector_const_iterator(vector_iterator<Vec_T> const &rhs)
        : container(rhs.container),
        ptr(rhs.ptr)
        {
        }

    ~vector_const_iterator()
        {
        }

    bool operator!=(this_t const &rhs) const
        {
        return (ptr != rhs.ptr);
        }

    bool operator!=(T *ptr_) const
        {
        return (ptr != ptr_);
        }

    bool operator==(this_t const &rhs) const
        {
        return (ptr == rhs.ptr);
        }

    bool operator==(T *ptr_) const
        {
        return (ptr == ptr_);
        }

    bool operator>(this_t const &rhs) const
        {
        return (ptr > rhs.ptr);
        }

    bool operator>(T *ptr_) const
        {
        return (ptr > ptr_);
        }

    bool operator>=(this_t const &rhs) const
        {
        return (ptr >= rhs.ptr);
        }

    bool operator>=(T *ptr_) const
        {
        return (ptr >= ptr_);
        }

    bool operator<(this_t const &rhs) const
        {
        return (ptr < rhs.ptr);
        }

    bool operator<(T *ptr_) const
        {
        return (ptr < ptr_);
        }

    bool operator<=(this_t const &rhs) const
        {
        return (ptr <= rhs.ptr);
        }

    bool operator<=(T *ptr_) const
        {
        return (ptr <= ptr_);
        }

    T const &operator*()
        {
        if (is_valid_ptr())
            {
            return (*ptr);
            }
        throw std::exception("vector_const_iterator: pointer out of safe range when dereferencing (operator*)");
        }

    T const *operator->()
        {
        if (is_valid_ptr())
            {
            return (ptr);
            }
        throw std::exception("vector_const_iterator: pointer out of safe range when dereferencing (operator->)");
        }

    this_t operator++(int)
        {
        this_t holder(*this);
        ++(*this);
        return (holder);
        }

    this_t &operator++()
        {
        ++ptr;
        return (*this);
        }

    this_t operator+=(unsigned offset)
        {
        ptr += offset;
        return (*this);
        }

    this_t &operator-=(unsigned offset)
        {
        ptr -= offset;
        return (*this);
        }

    T &operator[](unsigned offset) const
        {
        this_t holder(*this);
        holder.ptr += offset;
        if (holder.is_valid_ptr())
            {
            return (*(ptr + offset));
            }
        throw std::exception("vector_const_iterator: pointer out of safe range when dereferencing (operator[])");
        }

    this_t &operator=(this_t const &rhs)
        {
        ptr = rhs.ptr;
        return (*this);
        }

    this_t operator+(unsigned offset)
        {
        return (this_t(ptr + offset, container));
        }

    this_t operator-(unsigned offset)
        {
        return (this_t(ptr - offset, container));
        }

    unsigned operator-(this_t const &rhs)
        {
        return (ptr - rhs.ptr);
        }

    this_t operator--(int)
        {
        this_t holder(*this);
        --(*this);
        return (holder);
        }

    this_t &operator--()
        {
        --ptr;
        return (*this);
        }

    operator vector_iterator<Vec_T>()
        {
        return (vector_iterator<Vec_T>(ptr, container));
        }

private:
    Vec_T const &container;
    T *ptr;

    bool is_valid_ptr() const
        {
        return (ptr >= container.mem_start
            && ptr < container.seq_end);
        }

    bool is_valid_ptr2() const
        {
        return (ptr >= container.mem_start
            && ptr <= container.seq_end);
        }
    };

template<typename Vec_T>
class vector_const_reverse_iterator;

template<typename Vec_T>
class vector_reverse_iterator
    {
public:
    typedef vector_reverse_iterator<Vec_T> this_t;
    typedef typename Vec_T::value_type T;

    friend Vec_T;

    vector_reverse_iterator(T *ptr_, Vec_T const &cont)
        : container(cont),
        ptr(ptr_)
        {
        }

    vector_reverse_iterator(this_t const &rhs)
        : container(rhs.container),
        ptr(rhs.ptr)
        {
        }

    vector_reverse_iterator(vector_const_reverse_iterator<Vec_T> const &rhs)
        : container(rhs.container),
        ptr(rhs.ptr)
        {
        }

    ~vector_reverse_iterator()
        {
        }

    bool operator!=(this_t const &rhs) const
        {
        return (ptr != rhs.ptr);
        }

    bool operator!=(T *ptr_) const
        {
        return (ptr != ptr_);
        }

    bool operator==(this_t const &rhs) const
        {
        return (ptr == rhs.ptr);
        }

    bool operator==(T *ptr_) const
        {
        return (ptr == ptr_);
        }

    bool operator>(this_t const &rhs) const
        {
        return (ptr < rhs.ptr);
        }

    bool operator>(T *ptr_) const
        {
        return (ptr < ptr_);
        }

    bool operator>=(this_t const &rhs) const
        {
        return (ptr <= rhs.ptr);
        }

    bool operator>=(T *ptr_) const
        {
        return (ptr <= ptr_);
        }

    bool operator<(this_t const &rhs) const
        {
        return (ptr > rhs.ptr);
        }

    bool operator<(T *ptr_) const
        {
        return (ptr > ptr_);
        }

    bool operator<=(this_t const &rhs) const
        {
        return (ptr >= rhs.ptr);
        }

    bool operator<=(T *ptr_) const
        {
        return (ptr >= ptr_);
        }

    T &operator*()
        {
        if (is_valid_ptr())
            {
            return (*ptr);
            }
        throw std::exception("vector_reverse_iterator: pointer out of safe range when dereferencing (operator*)");
        }

    T *operator->()
        {
        if (is_valid_ptr())
            {
            return (ptr);
            }
        throw std::exception("vector_reverse_iterator: pointer out of safe range when dereferencing (operator->)");
        }

    this_t operator++(int)
        {
        this_t holder(*this);
        --(*this);
        return (holder);
        }

    this_t &operator++()
        {
        --ptr;
        return (*this);
        }

    this_t operator+=(unsigned offset)
        {
        ptr -= offset;
        return (*this);
        }

    this_t &operator-=(unsigned offset)
        {
        ptr += offset;
        return (*this);
        }

    T &operator[](unsigned offset) const
        {
        this_t holder(*this);
        holder.ptr -= offset;
        if (holder.is_valid_ptr())
            {
            return (*(ptr - offset));
            }
        throw std::exception("vector_reverse_iterator: pointer out of safe range when dereferencing (operator[])");
        }

    this_t &operator=(this_t const &rhs)
        {
        ptr = rhs.ptr;
        return (*this);
        }

    this_t operator+(unsigned offset)
        {
        return (this_t(ptr + offset, container));
        }

    this_t operator-(unsigned offset)
        {
        return (this_t(ptr - offset, container));
        }

    unsigned operator-(this_t const &rhs)
        {
        return (rhs.ptr - ptr);
        }

    this_t operator--(int)
        {
        this_t holder(*this);
        ++(*this);
        return (holder);
        }

    this_t &operator--()
        {
        --ptr;
        return (*this);
        }

    operator vector_const_reverse_iterator<Vec_T>()
        {
        return (vector_const_reverse_iterator<Vec_T>(ptr, container));
        }

private:
    Vec_T const &container;
    T *ptr;

    bool is_valid_ptr() const
        {
        return (ptr >= container.mem_start
            && ptr < container.seq_end);
        }

    bool is_valid_ptr2() const
        {
        return (ptr >= (container.mem_start - 1)
            && ptr < container.seq_end);
        }
    };

template<typename Vec_T>
class vector_const_reverse_iterator
    {
public:
    typedef vector_const_reverse_iterator<Vec_T> this_t;
    typedef typename Vec_T::value_type T;

    friend Vec_T;

    vector_const_reverse_iterator(T *ptr_, Vec_T const &cont)
        : container(cont),
        ptr(ptr_)
        {
        }

    vector_const_reverse_iterator(this_t const &rhs)
        : container(rhs.container),
        ptr(rhs.ptr)
        {
        }

    vector_const_reverse_iterator(vector_reverse_iterator<Vec_T> const &rhs)
        : container(rhs.container),
        ptr(rhs.ptr)
        {
        }

    ~vector_const_reverse_iterator()
        {
        }

    bool operator!=(this_t const &rhs) const
        {
        return (ptr != rhs.ptr);
        }

    bool operator!=(T *ptr_) const
        {
        return (ptr != ptr_);
        }

    bool operator==(this_t const &rhs) const
        {
        return (ptr == rhs.ptr);
        }

    bool operator==(T *ptr_) const
        {
        return (ptr == ptr_);
        }

    bool operator>(this_t const &rhs) const
        {
        return (ptr < rhs.ptr);
        }

    bool operator>(T *ptr_) const
        {
        return (ptr < ptr_);
        }

    bool operator>=(this_t const &rhs) const
        {
        return (ptr <= rhs.ptr);
        }

    bool operator>=(T *ptr_) const
        {
        return (ptr <= ptr_);
        }

    bool operator<(this_t const &rhs) const
        {
        return (ptr > rhs.ptr);
        }

    bool operator<(T *ptr_) const
        {
        return (ptr > ptr_);
        }

    bool operator<=(this_t const &rhs) const
        {
        return (ptr >= rhs.ptr);
        }

    bool operator<=(T *ptr_) const
        {
        return (ptr >= ptr_);
        }

    T const &operator*()
        {
        if (is_valid_ptr())
            {
            return (*ptr);
            }
        throw std::exception("vector_const_reverse_iterator: pointer out of safe range when dereferencing (operator*)");
        }

    T const *operator->()
        {
        if (is_valid_ptr())
            {
            return (ptr);
            }
        throw std::exception("vector_const_reverse_iterator: pointer out of safe range when dereferencing (operator->)");
        }

    this_t operator++(int)
        {
        this_t holder(*this);
        --(*this);
        return (holder);
        }

    this_t &operator++()
        {
        --ptr;
        return (*this);
        }

    this_t operator+=(unsigned offset)
        {
        ptr -= offset;
        return (*this);
        }

    this_t &operator-=(unsigned offset)
        {
        ptr += offset;
        return (*this);
        }

    T &operator[](unsigned offset) const
        {
        this_t holder(*this);
        holder.ptr -= offset;
        if (holder.is_valid_ptr())
            {
            return (*(ptr - offset));
            }
        throw std::exception("vector_const_reverse_iterator: pointer out of safe range when dereferencing (operator[])");
        }

    this_t &operator=(this_t const &rhs)
        {
        ptr = rhs.ptr;
        return (*this);
        }

    this_t operator+(unsigned offset)
        {
        return (this_t(ptr - offset, container));
        }

    this_t operator-(unsigned offset)
        {
        return (this_t(ptr + offset, container));
        }

    unsigned operator-(this_t const &rhs)
        {
        return (rhs.ptr - ptr);
        }

    this_t operator--(int)
        {
        this_t holder(*this);
        ++(*this);
        return (holder);
        }

    this_t &operator--()
        {
        ++ptr;
        return (*this);
        }

    operator vector_reverse_iterator<Vec_T>()
        {
        return (vector_reverse_iterator<Vec_T>(ptr, container));
        }

private:
    Vec_T const &container;
    T *ptr;

    bool is_valid_ptr() const
        {
        return (ptr >= container.mem_start
            && ptr < container.seq_end);
        }

    bool is_valid_ptr2() const
        {
        return (ptr >= (container.mem_start - 1)
            && ptr < container.seq_end);
        }
    };

template <typename T, typename A = std::allocator<T> >
class vector
    {
public:
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef value_type &reference;
    typedef value_type const &const_reference;
    typedef value_type *pointer;
    typedef value_type const *const_pointer;
    typedef vector<T, A> this_t;
    typedef A allocator_t;
    typedef vector_iterator<this_t> iterator;
    typedef vector_const_iterator<this_t> const_iterator;
    typedef vector_reverse_iterator<this_t> reverse_iterator;
    typedef vector_const_reverse_iterator<this_t> const_reverse_iterator;

    friend class iterator;
    friend class const_iterator;
    friend class reverse_iterator;
    friend class const_reverse_iterator;

    vector()
        : mem_start(pointer()),
        seq_end(pointer()),
        mem_end(pointer())
        {
        }

    vector(this_t const &rhs)
        : mem_start(pointer()),
        seq_end(pointer()),
        mem_end(pointer())
        {
        assign(rhs);
        }

    vector(unsigned count, value_type const &val = value_type())
        : mem_start(pointer()),
        seq_end(pointer()),
        mem_end(pointer())
        {
        assign(count, val);
        }

    template<unsigned N>
    vector(value_type (&arr)[N])
        : mem_start(pointer()),
        seq_end(pointer()),
        mem_end(pointer())
        {
        assign(&arr[0], &arr[N]);
        }

    vector(pointer start, pointer end)
        : mem_start(pointer()),
        seq_end(pointer()),
        mem_end(pointer())
        {
        assign(start, end);
        }

    ~vector()
        {
        wipe_all();
        }

    template<unsigned N>
    void assign(value_type (&arr)[N])
        {
        assign(&arr[0], &arr[N]);
        }

    void assign(unsigned count, value_type const &val = value_type())
        {
        value_type v = val;
        if (points_to(&val))
            {
            v = val;
            }
        if (is_clean() || size() == 0)
            {
            allocate(count);
            }
        else if (count < capacity())
            {
            wipe_values();
            }
        else
            {
            reallocate(count);
            wipe_values();
            }
            seq_end = std::uninitialized_fill_n(mem_start, count, v);
        }

    void assign(pointer first, pointer last)
        {
        if (!points_to(first) && !points_to(last))
            {
            if (is_clean() || size() == 0)
                {
                allocate(last - first);
                }
            else if ((last - first) < capacity())
                {
                wipe_values();
                }
            else
                {
                reallocate((last - first));
                wipe_values();
                }
                seq_end = std::uninitialized_copy(first, last, mem_start);
            }
        }

    void assign(this_t const &rhs)
        {
        if (&rhs != this)
            {
            if (rhs.size() <= capacity())
                {
                wipe_values();
                }
            else if (is_clean() || size() == 0)
                {
                allocate(rhs.size());
                }
            else
                {   
                reallocate(rhs.size());
                wipe_values();
                }
            seq_end = std::uninitialized_copy(rhs.mem_start, rhs.seq_end, mem_start);
            }
        }

    this_t &operator=(this_t const &rhs)
        {
        assign(rhs);
        return (*this);
        }

    void swap(this_t &rhs)
        {
        std::swap(mem_start, rhs.mem_start);
        std::swap(seq_end, rhs.seq_end);
        std::swap(mem_end, rhs.mem_end);
        }

    void push_front(const_reference value)
        {
        T to_push = value;
        if (points_to(&value))
            {
            to_push = value;
            }
        this_t holder;
        holder.allocate(capacity() + 1);
        holder.push_back(to_push);
        holder.seq_end = std::uninitialized_copy(mem_start, seq_end, holder.mem_start + 1);
        swap(holder);
        }

    void push_back(const_reference value)
        {
        T to_push = value;
        if (is_clean() || size() == 0)
            {
            allocate(2);
            }
        else if ((size() + 1) > capacity())
            {
            reallocate(capacity() * 1.5);
            }
        else if (points_to(&value))
            {
            to_push = value;
            }
        allocator_t al;
        al.construct(seq_end++, to_push);
        }

    void pop_front()
        {
        if ((mem_start + 1) == seq_end)
            {
            this_t holder;
            holder.allocate(capacity());
            swap(holder);
            }
        else
            {
            this_t holder(mem_start + 1, seq_end);
            holder.reallocate(capacity());
            swap(holder);
            }
        }

    void pop_back()
        {
        allocator_t al;
        al.destroy(seq_end - 1);
        --seq_end;
        }

    void insert(iterator position, const value_type &val)
        {
        if (position.is_valid_ptr2())
            {
            if (position == seq_end)
                {
                push_back(val);
                }
            else if (position = mem_start)
                {
                push_front(val);
                }
            else
                {
                this_t holder;
                holder.allocate(capacity() + 1);
                holder.seq_end = std::uninitialized_copy(mem_start, position, holder.mem_start);
                holder.push_back(val);
                holder.seq_end = std::uninitialized_copy(position, seq_end, holder.seq_end);
                swap(holder);
                }
            }
        }

    void insert(iterator position, unsigned count, const value_type &val)
        {
        if (position.is_valid_ptr2())
            {
            for (int i = 0; i < size(); ++i)
                {
                if (position == seq_end)
                    {
                    while (count--)
                        {
                        push_back(val);
                        }
                    }
                else if(position == mem_start)
                    {
                    while (count--)
                        {
                        push_front(val);
                        }
                    }
                else
                    {
                    this_t holder;
                    holder.allocate(capacity() + count);
                    holder.seq_end = std::uninitialized_copy(mem_start, position, holder.mem_start);
                    holder.seq_end = std::uninitialized_fill_n(holder.seq_end, count, val);
                    holder.seq_end = std::uninitialized_copy(position, seq_end, holder.seq_end);
                    swap(holder);
                    }   
                }
            }
        }

    void insert(iterator position, iterator first, iterator last)
        {
        if (first.is_valid_ptr() && last.is_valid_ptr2())
            {
            if (first == last)
                {
                insert(position, *first);
                }
            else if (first == begin())
                {
                while (last != first)
                    {
                    push_front(last--);
                    }
                }
            else if (last == end())
                {
                while (first != last)
                    {
                    push_back(first++);
                    }
                }
            else
                {
                this_t holder;
                allocator_t al;
                if (holder.allocate(capacity() + (last - first)))
                    {
                    holder.seq_end = std::uninitialized_copy(mem_start, first.ptr, holder.mem_start);
                    while (first != last)
                        {
                        push_back(first++);
                        }
                    holder.seq_end = std::uninitialized_copy((last.ptr + 1), seq_end, holder.seq_end);
                    swap(holder);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    void erase(iterator it)
        {
        if (it.is_valid_ptr())
            {
            if (it == mem_start)
                {
                pop_front();
                }
            else if (it == (seq_end - 1))
                {
                pop_back();
                }
            else
                {
                erase(it, it + 1);
                }
            }   
        }

    void erase(iterator start, iterator end_)
        {
        if (start.is_valid_ptr() && end_.is_valid_ptr2())
            {
            if (start == end_)
                {
                erase(start);
                }
            else if (start == begin())
                {
                while (end_-- != start)
                    {
                    pop_front();
                    }
                }
            else if (end_ == end())
                {
                while (end_-- != start)
                    {
                    pop_back();
                    }
                }
            else
                {
                this_t holder;
                allocator_t al;
                if (holder.allocate(capacity()))
                    {
                    holder.seq_end = std::uninitialized_copy(mem_start, start.ptr, holder.mem_start);
                    holder.seq_end = std::uninitialized_copy(end_.ptr, seq_end, holder.seq_end);
                    swap(holder);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    void clear()
        {
        wipe_values();
        seq_end = mem_start;
        }

    void reserve(unsigned count)
        {
        if (count < capacity())
            {
            reallocate(count);
            }
        }

    reference operator[](unsigned offset)
        {
        return (*(mem_start + offset));
        }

    const_reference operator[](unsigned offset) const
        {
        return (*(mem_start + offset));
        }

    reference at(unsigned offset)
        {
        return (*(begin() + offset));
        }

    const_reference at(unsigned offset) const
        {
        return (*(begin() + offset));
        }

    reference front()
        {
        return (*(begin()));
        }

    const_reference front() const
        {
        return (*(cbegin()));
        }

    reference back()
        {
        return (*(end() - 1));
        }

    const_reference back() const
        {
        return (*(cend() - 1));
        }

    iterator begin()
        {
        return (iterator(mem_start, (*this)));
        }

    iterator end()
        {
        return (iterator(seq_end, (*this)));
        }

    const_iterator cbegin()
        {
        return (const_iterator(mem_start, (*this)));
        }

    const_iterator cend()
        {
        return (const_iterator(seq_end, (*this)));
        }

    reverse_iterator rbegin()
        {
        return (reverse_iterator(seq_end - 1, (*this)));
        }

    reverse_iterator rend()
        {
        return (reverse_iterator(mem_start - 1, (*this)));
        }

    const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const
        {
        return (const_reverse_iterator(seq_end - 1, (*this)));
        }

    const_reverse_iterator crend() const
        {
        return (const_reverse_iterator(mem_start - 1, (*this)));
        }

    iterator make_iterator(unsigned offset)
        {
        return (iterator(mem_start + offset, (*this)));
        }

    iterator make_iterator(reference position)
        {
        return (iterator(&position, (*this)));
        }

    const_iterator make_const_iterator(unsigned offset)
        {
        return (const_iterator(mem_start + offset, (*this)));
        }

    const_iterator make_const_iterator(reference position)
        {
        return (const_iterator(&position, (*this)));
        }

    void shrink_to_fit()
        {
        if (size() < capacity())
            {
            this_t holder = *this;
            swap(holder);
            }
        }

    unsigned size() const
        {
        return (seq_end - mem_start);
        }

    unsigned capacity() const
        {
        return (mem_end - mem_start);
        }

    bool empty() const
        {
        return (is_clean() || size() == 0);
        }

private:
    pointer mem_start, seq_end, mem_end;

    bool points_to(const_pointer ptr)
        {
        return (ptr >= mem_start && ptr <= seq_end);
        }

    bool allocate(unsigned size)
        {
        mem_start = pointer();
        seq_end = pointer();
        mem_end = pointer();
        allocator_t al;
        if (size < al.max_size())
            {
            mem_start = al.allocate(size);
            seq_end = mem_start;
            mem_end = mem_start + size;
            return (true);
            }
        return (false);
        }

    void reallocate(unsigned size)
        {
        allocator_t al;
        while (size == capacity())
            {
            size *= 2;
            }
        pointer new_memstart = al.allocate(size), new_seqend;
        new_seqend = std::uninitialized_copy(mem_start, seq_end, new_memstart);
        wipe_all();
        if (allocate(size))
            {
            seq_end = std::uninitialized_copy(new_memstart, new_seqend, mem_start);
            }
        }

    void wipe_values()
        {
        allocator_t al;
        if (!is_clean())
            {
            unsigned sz = size(), sz2 = size();
            while (sz-- != 0)
                {
                al.destroy(mem_start++);
                }
            mem_start -= sz2;
            }
        }

    void wipe_all()
        {
        if (!is_clean())
            {
            allocator_t al;
            wipe_values();
            unsigned cp = capacity();
            al.deallocate(mem_start, cp);
            }
        }

    bool is_clean() const
        {
        return (mem_start == pointer() &&
            seq_end == pointer() && mem_end == pointer());
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: `reverse_iterator` is specified to be `reverse_iterator<iterator>`. You are not allowed to roll out your own `vector_reverse_iterator`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a rather large amount of code here, so I'm just going to make some comments as I find things.

```
void reallocate(unsigned size)
    {
    allocator_t al;
    while (size == capacity())
        {
        size *= 2;
        }
```

This looks like it might be a bug, did you mean to do `while size <= capacity` instead?

Additionally you probably want to check for overflow here too otherwise bad things will happen, make sure `size*2` actually fits into an `unsigned`.

Also I might be biased slightly because I've been using Python a lot lately but I particularly dislike declaring variables like this:

```
pointer new_memstart = al.allocate(size), new_seqend;
```

Putting one variable per line I find much nicer.

One thing I notice here is duplicated code for the operators in a few places. Specifically I'd implement as many operators as possible in terms of other operators. For example:

```
bool operator==(this_t const &rhs) const
    {
    return (ptr == rhs.ptr);
    }

bool operator!=(this_t const &rhs) const
    {
    return (ptr != rhs.ptr);
    }
```

would become:

```
bool operator==(this_t const &rhs) const
    {
    return (ptr == rhs.ptr);
    }

bool operator!=(this_t const &rhs) const
    {
    return !operator==(rhs);
    }
```

You can do this for a bunch of the operators, which will help the maintainability of the code.

Now while the following is not *exactly* duplicated:

```
bool is_valid_ptr() const
    {
    return (ptr >= container.mem_start
        && ptr < container.seq_end);
    }

bool is_valid_ptr2() const
    {
    return (ptr >= container.mem_start
        && ptr <= container.seq_end);
    }
```

It looks very similar. A comment explaining why these 2 seemingly similar functions exist and when to which version would be good. While most of the code seems self-explanatory the places that are less obvious would greatly benefit from some documentation.

EDIT as per the comments:

I might be inclined to rewrite the pointer validity check functions as follows:

```
/** Check if the pointer is a valid location in the container */
bool is_valid_ptr() const
    {
    return (ptr >= container.mem_start
        && ptr < container.seq_end);
    }

/** Check if the pointer is a valid location in the container or is the end pointer */
bool is_valid_ptr_or_end() const
    {
    return (is_valid_ptr() || ptr == container.seq_end);
    }
```

This change makes it a lot clearer to the reader what is going on here.

Comment: Ok.. So, on my code on my laptop, it is infact `size <= capacity()`; I must have copied it wrong. is_valid_ptr is to test if iterators point within the sequence (as in they point to somewhere with a value which is why the first iterators are tested for this). is_valid_ptr2 is used to test if they point within the sequence or point to the end of the sequence [undefinded], but it is only used on end iterators when their value is not copied in the function

Comment: I edited in light of that comment, that information would be really good somewhere in the code itself.